# While comparing two versions of Simulink model, how to compare a Simulink model with empty model?

Tags: matlab, compare, simulink

I am trying to compare model versions and extract what is added/deleted/modified by querying the difference tree. The difference tree can be programmatically obtained through slxmlcomp [Doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/exporting-printing-and-saving-comparison-results.html?searchHighlight=slxmlcomp.compare&s_tid=srchtitle_slxmlcomp.compare_2)

```
Edits = slxmlcomp.compare(ModelA_before, ModelA_after).
```

Is there a neat way to compare an empty model with a model? For instance, I want to compare a Simulink model file that doesnot exist before and now a new Simulink model file is added.

Current Approach:  The Edits Object (which is read only ) will have a left and right tree. I need the left tree to have practically nothing (or root only.) I have been doing the comparison by comparing the added file vs [deleting content](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulink.subsystem.deletecontents.html) . This way of comparison still leaves behind configuration being modified rather than added.

Comment: What do you expect the "compare" to look like when _everything_ is different because it's all new?

Comment: The Edits Object (which is read only ) will have a left and right tree. I need the left tree to have practically nothing (or root only.) I have been doing the comparison by comparing the added file vs deleting content https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulink.subsystem.deletecontents.html . This way of comparison still leaves behind configuration being modified rather than added.